# Align two TextViews at the start of the button and at the end of the button

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to align two textviews below a button. One at the start of the button and one at the end. How would I do so in ConstraintLayout?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the start of your left textview to the start of the button; set the end of the 2nd textview to the end of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```